# Implementation of stack in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-structures

I had an abstract idea of implementing a stack in MySQL. Tried a lot of Google work but couldn't reach to any logical conclusion.

The Stack must be a collection of tables with the stack top pointing at a particular table. We may have various such stacks in our DB. The stack length may increase if for example the field from the table is full. Likewise the stack length may decrease in the opposite manner!

Could you please give me an implementation idea! is it really possible at first place? Hope I'm clear with my question.

Comment: Which sort of object do you want the stack to store?

Comment: Why would you have the stack "pointing at a particular table"?  A data structure in a database that supports stacks would have one row per stack element.

Comment: I would go away and read up about the concepts of a RDMS. You idea should just remain abstract.

Answer (score 1):

My idea.

Single table with auto increment id and blob column where you store serialized objects.

Push on stack will insert with new highest id.

Pop from stack will get row with highest id and delete.

That is of course a simple approach. You must respect the origin of the stack push so you can only get stack objects you are allowed to. But that depends on the use case.

Comment: I was just about to write a similar answer.  Most uses of a stack do not need to persist between runs of a program, and do not need to be shared between instances of a program, which makes memory a better place to implement a stack.

Comment: Might add a threadId field as well so multiple threads can use the same table.  A parentId field might help with speed (backing out of the stack).